# How to create third partition on a Mac with Mavericks and Bootcamp?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, fat32

Right now I am running OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) on my MacBook Pro, with Windows 7 via Boot Camp, and I also have a third FAT32 partition where I share data between Mac/Windows.

I am going to upgrade to Mavericks. I Googled and it seems Mavericks is not going to be happy with letting me create the third FAT32 partition.

Did anyone create a third partition with Mavericks before? What are the steps?

(I have backed up all my data from both OS X and Windows, and I am going to format whole hard disk, and fresh install snow leopard, then update to Mavericks).

Answer (score 2):

Wait, before you do that, you can do this in an easier fashion.

Just shrink the Mac partition via Disk Utility and format the new free space as FAT32.

Comment: I have another had disk that with same configuration (one partition for Snow Leopard, one partition for Win7 Boocamp, and one FAT32 data partition). I updated to Marvicks while having this hard disk on my mac, and I have two problems:
1. becasue of third partition, installer says it is unusal partition configuration, and did not create the Recovery Partition.
2. It does not boot to Bootcamp anymore!

So I figure I should do a clean install

Answer (score 2):

The process for creating an extra partition in Mavericks hasn't changed much since Snow Leopard, so you should be able to create a partition using Disk Utility the same way you did in Snow Leopard.

Comment: Doesn't the recovery partition of Marvicks create problems for this procedure?

Comment: No, once Mavericks is installed, the Recovery partition doesn't even appear in the Disk Utility panel. So, you can just create partitions as you would usually.

Comment: When partitions are modified, during the process, the log actually states "Manipulating Recovery partition". It's all done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same config in my Lion but now with the new mavericks I tried it twice:
1) installed WIN7 and then reduced the Macintosh partition before creating a 3rd partition in disc utility. Result: Bootcamp not bootable anymore but the other 2 partitions worked fine
2) same same except that I now let disc utility devide the macintosh partition. Result was also same. 
Still looking for the answer. I think my next step will be partition magic or the like.

Comment: try this: after you install Win7 via bootcamp, devide the mac partition, and create 3rd partition with disk utility. Boot camp windows wont boot. now you need to boot via win7 CD/USB, via recovery mode, go to command prompt and REPAIR the boot specifications. (go to command, and rub FIXBOOT C:, where C is your windows partition).
good luck.